# SQL Server and distributed databases. How synchronize?

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, distributed

I'm planning a project for managing multiple distributed databases and I am raising the question of how to efficiently synchronize the data.

The project will be developed with technology. NET and SQL Server.

There will be a local database in which the company will load data, some of these data (not all) should be synchronized with a database that resides on the web. Similarly, the web database have to read data in the local database.

Basically there are tables that are "shared", but this is not a true replication, in some cases the information to transfer must be filtered according to certain criteria.

My question is: How do I manage this? which is the most efficient method?

I did some test using the Linked Servers and it works, but does not seem the most reliable solution. Are there synchronization mechanisms? Or is the use of web services better?

My main concern is how to handle the scenario where the connection to the web database is offline, perhaps providing a synchronization mechanisms that become active when the database back online.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication would be my first recommendation. You can create filters in replication such that only certain rows are replicated and it can handle offline scenarios. If that did not work for you, then you might look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/cc470041.aspx).